# What is the correct format for this date time response

Tags: ios, swift, date, codable

Im trying to use `codable` to decode a json response into a model but am having trouble with parsing the date.

The format im using in `DateFormatter` is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"` and a sample of the data

```
{
    "startDate": "2019-01-27T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2019-02-02T00:00:00",
    "id": null
}, {
    "startDate": "2019-01-20T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2019-01-26T00:00:00",
    "id": null
}, {
    "startDate": "2019-01-13T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2019-01-19T00:00:00",
    "id": null
}, {
    "startDate": "2019-01-13T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2020-01-19T00:00:00",
    "id": null
}, {
    "startDate": "2019-01-06T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2019-01-12T00:00:00",
    "id": null
}
```

I've also tried `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"`, `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`, and `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` with and without the `'` around the `T`

the error im getting is

> "NSCodingPath": [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "startDate", intValue: nil)], "NSDebugDescription": "Date string does not match format expected by formatter."

I'm sure i got the format right but that error makes me question my sanity.

I got the formats from https://nsdateformatter.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. Your strings have seconds (so include `:ss`), but no milliseconds (i.e., do not include `.SSS`) nor timezone qualifier (i.e., do not include `Z`, either).

The interesting question for me is what timezone should it assume. By default, in the absence of timezone portion to the string, `DateFormatter` will assume local timezone, even though there’s a good chance these are GMT/UTC/Zulu. If so, explicitly set the `timeZone` of the formatter. And, of course, don’t forget to set `locale`.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)     // include this only if dates are GMT/UTC/Zulu
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

---

By the way, you can, if you want, also use `ISO8601DateFormatter`, which assumes UTC/GMT, if you want:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withTime, .withColonSeparatorInTime]
```

And, in that case, if you want to use the local time zone, you’d have to specify it:

```
formatter.timeZone = .current
```

Unfortunately, with `dateDecodingStrategy` and cannot use `ISO8601DateFormatter`. Likewise the `.iso8601` strategy assumes you’ll have the timezone character.

So, with `Codable` and your particular strings, you have to stick with `DateFormatter` example, above.

Comment: so its that damn `Z` thats kicking my ass. I really appreciate the long answer, especially since i didnt consider timezone.

Answer (score -1):

The `Z` format specifier is unnecessary since the date strings don't include a timezone offset.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain yourself? OP confirmed this was the issue.